# Bitwise AND doesn't work and forbid further access to variable (while it works in the watcher)

Tags: c++, arrays, hex, codeblocks, bitwise-and

I'm currently trying to compare a value from a `std::array`, and an hexadecimal value. The code is as follow:

```
void function(std::array<uint8_t, 64 * 32>& to_render) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
            if (to_render[i*64 + j] & 0x80) {
                do_something()...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When If I write `to_render[i*64 + j] & 0x80` into the watcher, I get the expected result (depending on the `to_render[i*64 + j]` value).

For example, if
`to_render[i*64 + j] = 128`,
then
`to_render[i*64 + j] & 0x80 == 0x80`.

But when it's done in the code, it never works. Before the test, if I take a look at the `to_render[i*64 + j]` value, I have a value. But then, the test is always false (even when it should be true), and after that the watcher displays `error reading variable` for `to_render[i*64 + j]`.

Do you have any idea where it could come from ? I can't find the problem by myself.

Cheers

EDIT:

In the original code, I added this snippet of code:

```
if (to_render[i*m_size.first + j] != 0x00) {
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(to_render[i*m_size.first + j]) << std::dec << " " << static_cast<int>(to_render[i*m_size.first + j]) << std::endl;
}
```

To check what the value is. What is weird is that it always print `1` for both, but the value is something else in the watcher. I'm casting the `uint8_t` to `int` for display purposes (else it prints ASCII symbols in the console).

If I use this snippet of code

```
uint8_t test_value = 0x80;
int result = test_value & 0x80;
if (result) {
    std::cout << "It worked" << std::endl;
}

if (test_value & 0x80) {
    std::cout << "It worked too" << std::endl;
}
```

It works as intended. I tried it by replacing `uint8_t test_value = to_render[0]`, and it works as well.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `i*64 + j` instead of `i*j + j`?

Comment: What happens when you try it with one `uint8_t`, rather than an element of an array? You've been told before about [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux that's exact. First mistake here... Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Beta it works with one `uint8_t` value. I added a few informations about my case in the original post.